# Find the indicated quantities from the given data

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors, mathematics, equilibrium

This is a **vector application**.

A rope is hung at both ends from a horizontal beam, and a weight m is suspended from it as shown in the *figure*. The left part of the rope exerts a force G at P, while the right part of the rope exerts a force H. Find the indicated quantities from the given data.

[image: this is the figure]

$m = 50 \textrm{kg}$ , $\theta = 17°$, $\Phi = 6°$

$$\left | G \right | = \textrm{?}$$
$$\left |H \right | = \textrm{?}$$

Hope you could explain it on how you solve it. Thank you!

Comment: choose p as center of Cartesian system and disintegrate the forces acting on it....bear in mind system is balanced in forces hence  Sigma F = 0 ....you get two equations for x and y...solve them...and you get the desired solution.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site; but, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as this is a homework question, I can't tell you the complete solution.

Choose P as the origin of coordinate system and resolve the forces into x and y component. And as the body is in equilibrium, the net force is zero. So you get these two relations (when the net force on x and y component equated to zero.) 
$$G\cos\theta=H\cos\phi\\  
G\sin\theta+H\sin\phi=mg$$

solving these two equation will lead you the required result.